# Is it possible to actively develop julia packages in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I want to import and use functions, structs, and modules from my local julia project under active development named MyProject.jl.

If I cd to my project directory, then activate the project, then call jupyter notebook and run:

```
include("../src/MyProject.jl")
using .MyProject
```

I can use the project objects normally.  But if I make a change to the project files the change is not reflected in jupyter.  It seems to require a kernel restart.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Are you using Revise.jl (https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl)? Is it also in your startup config?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl), and you have a `Project.toml` file (i.e. an environment dedicated to your project created using `Pkg.activate` or `PkgTemplates`) in your project root directory (`MyProject` in your example), then you only need to activate the project environment instead of including source files explicitly.

```
import Pkg
Pkg.activate("../")
using MyProject
```

Revise will then track the changes that you make to your project source files in `MyProject/src/`.